# Angular - Module Separation - Best Practice for shared or common code

Tags: angular, typescript, separation-of-concerns, angular-module

I have some Angular services that have identical methods for parsing the json response, handling errors etc (eg. trapping if it's a 422 error for example).

Obviously I don't want these methods copy and pasted into each service, but I cannot seem to find any guidance on where I should put this code.

They are not class methods, just currently identical private methods in each service.

Here's one for example:

```
   private parseToString(jsonResponse: any){
    return Object.keys(jsonResponse).reduce(
      (prev, next) => prev.concat(jsonResponse[next].map(
        v => next + ' ' + v).join(', ')), []).join(', ');
  }
```

Is there some way to create a helper module or something like a Rails Concern that you can include?

Say for example I have this folder:

app/services

which has my various .ts service files.

I could create "app/services/helpers" folder and put a file inside that...but what goes into that .ts file?

eg. parser-helper.ts could be the file name, but what does the code inside that look like? Should it be a module? If so, how can I include it into the service?

For example, is this the recommended way to do it?

app/services/helpers/parser-helper.module.ts

```
module parserHelperModule {

  export function helperA(){}
  export function helperB(){}

}
```

Comment: Well TypeScript has functions, classes, methods, etc. You're free to create a function, export it from a module, and import it and use it wherever you want.

Comment: I added some example code that I think is what you mean for me to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the common code as a common service itself as below

```
export class CommonService {
    public parseToString(jsonResponse: any){
            return Object.keys(jsonResponse).reduce(
                        (prev, next) => prev.concat(jsonResponse[next].map(
                            v => next + ' ' + v).join(', ')), []).join(', ');
  }  
   public someOtherMethod(){

   }
}
```

So you can import the class anywhere accross the application and use them

Note: When you are defining common methods in to a single service, make sure they are public

**Update 1** :

Yes it is a good practice to use a separate module that serves all the common codes and making the main AppModule to import the **CommonModule** which would look like.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:    [ 
                HttpModule, Logger, Toaster, ... 
              ],
  declarations: [ CommonCmoponents
                ],
  providers:[Service1, Service2 ]
})
export class CommonModule { }
```

Make sure that your common module just serves as a collection, this CommonModule should not contain

1. Browser Module
2. Bootstrapping Components

You might be look for a the below image to have separation of concerns

[image]

Comment: Thanks but for some reason it strikes me as odd or overkill to create a service. Or at least a bit mis-leading as 'CommonService' is not really a service in its own right, but just some helper code.

Comment: if you dont want it to be service serve it without @Injectable() and it remains a simple class

Comment: Ah I see. And your update is probably more what I was thinking (coming from a Rails background) so thanks, I learned a lot from your answers.

Comment: @rmcsharry have a look at the update one which gives much more details

Comment: thanks for the update, the diagram helps a lot to understand this!

Comment: happy to help you. :) share the same spread knowledge. If  you can change the title of the post to make search optimised

Answer (score 5):

In parser-helper.ts:

```
export function parseToString(jsonResponse: any): string {
    ...
}
```

In any other TypeScript file:

```
import { parseToString } from './relative/path/to/parser-helper';

...
const s = parseToString(response);
```

Comment: This is interesting - no module involved at all. Is this the recommended way to share common code in an Angular2 app?

Comment: There are two modules involved. As explained in [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), *In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module.*

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that link, and the italics. I wish I could mark two answers as correct now!