# Angular2: Architecture and Modularization as Git-Projects

Tags: git, angular, module, architecture, continuous-integration

I want to port an app's frontend to an Angular2 Single-Page-Application. It's possible that the project gets other developers working in parallel on it, so I want to separate the client into multiple logical units with respective repositories. If you look at this example from some other person here:

[Angular2 - Separation of Concerns Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328596/angular2-separation-of-concerns-best-practice)
[image]
my idea was to make one main git repo for {AppModule, SharedModule, RouterModule, Material-Design, index.html, ... }, separate repos for each Feature and also one repo for methods and services which are not always available but are used by components inside multiple other repos (e.g. Common Module with LoggerService etc). Does this structure make sense? Would you recommend to nest the repos (I have yet to look into how it works in Git but I'm sure its possible) or have them all at top level?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me and I would not recommend it.  Instead, consider just using separate _branches_ in a _single_ repository.

Comment: It's an interesting pattern.  You can create versioned feature modules, and have it integrate your application (main app module). It follows MicroServices architecture and supports continuous delivery. I like it...  I would separate the services module (which integrate with Web Services) from the UI module - its a nice separation of concerns, and lets you more easily change the UI later